# Passing selected option to method and access data attributes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to access the data attributes from a select option passed to a method.  Is this possible?

As an example, suppose I have a select list in my html as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
  <option value="1" data-data1="AB" data-data2="WX">Route1</option>
  <option value="2" data-data1="CD" data-data2="YZ">Route2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Wiring up an event handler and getting the user's selection and even accessing the data attributes within the event handler is fine.

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $("select[name='mySelect']").on('change', function () {
    var selection = $(this).find('option:selected');
    //no problem accessing the attributes here:
    var data1 = selected.data('data1');
    var data2 = selected.data('data2');

    //but what if I want to pass the selection object to a method?
    doSomething(selection);
  });
});
```

Neither of the approaches of retrieving the attribute values in the following method work.  Is this possible?  If so, what am I missing?

```
function doSomething(selection)
{
    var data1 = selection.data('data1');
    var data2 = selection.data('data2');

    var data3 = $(selection).data('data1');
    var data4 = $(selection).data('data2');
}
</script>
```

Comment: well you use a name selector and it has an id... and inside you have selected and that is not even a variable... Fix those and it works..

Comment: yeah, sorry, I was just knocking up an example quickly and omitted the name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typos aside, your code works fine.

1. I changed the selector for the `change` event to `#mySelect`, since your `select` element didn't have a `name` attribute.
2. You're storing the selected `option` into a variable called `selection`, but on the lines that followed (`var data1 = selected.data('data1');`) you were calling a non-existent variable called `selected` which crashed your JS.

```js
$("#mySelect").on('change', function() {
  var selection = $(this).find('option:selected');
  doSomething(selection);
});

function doSomething(selection) {
  var data1 = selection.data('data1');
  var data2 = selection.data('data2');
  console.log('data1', data1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="1" data-data1="AB" data-data2="WX">Route1</option>
    <option value="2" data-data1="CD" data-data2="YZ">Route2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: cheers.  The problem was I'm an idiot ;)  There was a bug in the code that was populating the options and as such, the data attributes were not being set.